# How do I append a double quote (") to the end of a var

Tags: linux, bash, append, quote

I'm working with renaming a bunch of files and directories that have spaces in them. I've got a list of directories like:

```
"/usr/home/name/directory a/"
"/usr/home/name/directory b/"
```

etc...

They are all surrounded in double quotes so that I can use a for loop to work with each. That part is working fine. The trouble is that I also have files like:

```
"/usr/home/name/directory a/file a"
"/usr/home/name/directory b/file b"
```

etc...

I need to verify that the directory that the file is in, is writable. So to do that I am getting the dirname from the string like:

```
dnam=$(dirname $1)
```

And that works ... to a point. The end result is that my last double-quote is cut off as well, resulting in:

```
"/usr/home/name/directory a
"/usr/home/name/directory b
```

etc...

I need the final quote to be able to move onto the actual renaming portion and cannot figure out how to do it. I'm sure it's something simple I'm overlooking. Can someone fill me in please?

Comment: You may need to provide a little more detail on what you're attempting, but at a glance do you need to add back slashes to escape the double quotes in your script?

Answer (score 2):

For safety if nothing else, use:

```
dnam=$(dirname "$1")
```

with double quotes around the variable.

You can append a double quote to that result with:

```
dnam=$(dirname "$1")'"'
```

or a number of equivalent notations.  However, I'm suspicious that you should be handling the names differently, without the double quotes in the values.  That is, you might have:

```
dir1="/usr/home/name/directory a"
file1="$dir1/file a"
```

and then when you need to pass one of these to a command, you enclose it in double quotes:

```
dnam=$(dirname "$file1")

cd "$dnam"
```

If you're dealing with lists of such names, use an array, and then notations such as:

```
a=( "$dir1" "$dir2" )

ls -ld "${a[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

At a glance, it seems you need to add back slashes to escape the double quotes in your script.

Comment: doh! Yep. I knew it was something simple. I must be getting tired. Thank you. Watch for my next question comping up in just a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version without the need of a subshell:

```
dnam=${1%/*}\"
```

The parameter substitution has the same effect as the utility dirname. It works with blanks in the path. The final quote needs just to be escaped.